# Discord.py Not recognising members

Tags: python, discord.py

My Discord bot doesn't recognise members in a voice channel before the have switched to at least 1 other voice channel after the bot has started (after joining the channel, a user has to manually change to a different channel, then return, for the bot to recognise the member and be able to move them to the desired channel). This is a bit counterintuative, and defeats the purpose of my bot.

```
from discord.ext import commands


class Mute(commands.Cog):

    # Commands
    @commands.command()
    async def mute(self, ctx):
        vc = ctx.author.voice.channel
        for member in vc.members:
            await member.edit(mute=True)
            await ctx.channel.purge()

    @commands.command()
    async def unmute(self, ctx):
        vc = ctx.author.voice.channel
        for member in vc.members:
            await member.edit(mute=False)
            await ctx.channel.purge()

    @commands.command()
    async def start(self, ctx):
        vc = ctx.author.voice.channel
        await ctx.channel.send("A new game has started!")
        await ctx.channel.send("Users will now be moved. Game has started!")
        await ctx.channel.purge()
        channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name="AU voice")
        for member in vc.members:
            await member.move_to(channel)


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Mute(client))
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your discord.py to latest version and follow this tutorial on `discord.py` official docs:
[A Primer to Gateway Intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html)

Comment: Thanks, will check it out!